# Static access to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, static

please how to find  and use RichTextBox from static void? 
I am using c# Windows form application . I need static void becouse i need to call it from other class..

```
public static void setfont(int font)
{

}
```

so i can call it `main.setfont(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));`
but i cant change text in my richtextbox 
`"richtextbox.text = "idk""`
Please help . thx :D
[there on picture u can see there isnt my richtextbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6kul.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run only one instance of such form, then you can store instance into static field in the constructor. Then you can access the instance from static methods.

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    static Form1 _instance;

    public Form()
    {
        _instance = this;
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    public static void SomeStaticMethod()
    {
        _instance.richTextBox1.Text = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Note: missing `null` check if form is not created, but someone call the method.

Comment: Thank you . it works D: now i can change my font.